# Android phonegap hello world stops application launch

Tags: android, cordova

This is simple hello world.
but i can not run it.

When i try to run then it shows:
"Sorry! the application has stopped unexpectedly! Please Try again."
And it throws an exception. I have attached the exception here:

[image: enter image description he<code>enter code here</code>re]

//==========code==========

```
package com.ismail.phonegap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class HomePage extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

Comment: Did you change the `android-manifest.xml` file with the proper user permissions. If you have done it, then try doing this. Right click on the project and configure build path and set the jar file to add external jars and check the checkbox to use libraries. If it doesn't work then reply.

Comment: Paste your logs here....

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you put phonegap jar file in libs folder and also check for that you put plugin.xml file in res folder.

Comment: with the phonegap.jar file you need to make sure you import it into Java Build Path (as this is not always automatically done). Right click on your project, scroll down and click on propertis. Then select 'Jaca Build Path' from the left column and make sure you phonegap.jar is there, if not use the Add JARs to import it.

Comment: in libs folder i added cordova-2.0.0.jar  and in assets/www/ i added cordova-2.0.0.js file. There is no phonegap.jar or phonegap.js . From where can i get it?

Comment: Right click on project and then Build Path-> Configure Build Path-> Libraries-> Add External Library-> Browse and then add your cordova jar file and ya also make sure that you add xml folder in res folder and add plugin.xml file